# Removing Balls from an urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is the standard sheldon ross problem. There are $20$ red balls , $10$ blue balls and $8$ green balls. What is the probability that all the red balls have been removed before all the blue balls a re removed.

Now I know that this question has been asked before. But my question is a bit different.

I know intuitively that the answer should be $\frac{1}{3}$ which is the probability of drawing the last ball is blue.

But I have derived an expression in terms of a finite summation to describe the probability and the expression indeed evaluates to $\frac{1}{3}$ (Using software, specifically desmos) . My question is how to prove that the summation evaluates to $\frac{1}{3}$ by using algebra and not just brute force calculation.

The expression I derived:-
Consider from the end that there are $r$ green balls. So the last blue ball lies before the last r green balls.

So our expression for the probability is

$$\displaystyle \frac{\frac{1}{9!20!}\sum_{r=0}^{8}\frac{(37-r)!}{(8-r)!}}{\frac{38!}{20!10!8!}}$$.

Now this evaluates to $\frac{1}{3}$ . But how do I evaluate it using hand and not just by brute force by using a computer software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make calculation easier say that we draw all $38$ balls . From $38$ draws $8$ are green, from the remaining $30$ draws $20$ are red, and the rest are blue. Total possibilities are given below

$$
\binom{38}{8}\cdot\binom{30}{20}
$$

Now say that we run out of red first before we run out of blue. Still we have $8$ green from $38$ draws. However, we have $20$ red from the first $29$ non - green draws. Total possibilities are given below

$$
\binom{38}{8}\cdot\binom{29}{20}
$$

The probability is then

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\binom{38}{8}\cdot\binom{29}{20}}{\binom{38}{8}\cdot\binom{30}{20}}&=\frac{\frac{29!}{20!\cdot 9!}}{\frac{30!}{20!\cdot 10!}}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{3}
\end{align}
$$